# The best method to implement a "where" select filter in Angular JS with Laravel 4 and Pagination

Tags: angularjs, pagination, laravel-4, where-clause

I would like to paginate results and filter results by category from my database using Angular JS and Laravel 4. My current app works fine for pagination, and filters results returned from the database, but I want to add a category filter that returns paginated results by a category on page load, and each time a page is clicked. Should I set a global variable for category, pass that in my factory query and then in my php router create a where statement? Or is there some built in Angular JS magic to do this? Or would it be best to load my whole database on pageload and filter "on the fly" from the returned array?

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexeime/Rd8MG/106/) of the code I am working with

```
app.factory('Career', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('http://localhost/guitarraps.com/public/posts?callback=JSON_CALLBACK&page=:page&category='+category, {
    page: 1
    }, {
        'get': {
            method: 'JSONP'
        }
    });
});
```

An Example Route

```
Route::get( 'posts', function() {
    $term = Input::get('category');
    $vec =  Vector::where('category', 'LIKE', '%'.$term.'%')->paginate(2);
    return Response::json($vec)->setCallback(Input::get('callback'));
});
```

I am very new to Angular, any help would be greatly appreciated. Please let me know if I need to specify some more details.